# What is the difference between these three types in yaml file?

Tags: yaml

1:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes:es01,es02,es03
```

2:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes:  
  es01  
  es02  
  es03
```

3:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes:  
  - es01  
  - es02  
  - es03
```

Is 1 equals to 3? What is the difference?

I know 1 and 2 is totally different, but what exactly? And waht is the differecnt between 1 and 3

Comment: Please post the yaml examples directly in your post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both examples 1 and 3 achieve the same result of specifying a list of three nodes as the initial master nodes for the Elasticsearch cluster. Example 3 is often considered more readable and easier to maintain, especially as the number of nodes in the cluster grows, but both examples achieve the same result.

Comment: Sorry, Alon... I was editing the content.. Can't really make it right..

Comment: I see now. Both examples 1 and 3 achieve the same result of specifying a list of three nodes as the initial master nodes for the Elasticsearch cluster. Example 3 is often considered more readable and easier to maintain, especially as the number of nodes in the cluster grows, but both examples achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks, now I know where goes wrong!